# How can I use my model into tensorflow for android?

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I have a model trained on Keras (version 2.3.1) that I exported as a .h5 file and want to use in android. I downloaded the tensorflow for android implementation and tried to import my file without success. To do this I converted to .pb and got errors with input labels that I didn't know how to solve.

So I searched a little more and found the tensorflow lite for android (from [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/lite/examples/speech_commands/android/README.md)), so I converted my model to the .tflite format and tried to import it but without success. I get the following error when I change the default model to mine on this tensorflow for android pre-built app:

`Invalid input Tensor index: 1`

Converter code that I used to go from .h5 to .tflite:

```
import tensorflow as tf
model=tf.keras.models.load_model('./MyModel.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
converter.experimental_new_converter = True
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_22_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

I also installed **tf-nightly** via **pip** to do this conversion. I tried both with tensorflow 1.14 and 2.0 and nothing seems to work.

Can someone please help me?

This model is from a friend, and it is working normally.

Answer (score 0):

Good work on doing the prior research. `Invalid input Tensor index: 1` indicates that during the time of saved model conversion you need to specify input dimensions before converting them to tflite.

Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api#end-to-end_mobilenet_conversion_) out. Tf documentation to convert Keras model to tflite.

In order to find the input dimensions of your model you can ask your friend who trained this model or try using this code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./MyModel.h5')
print(model.summary())
```

Comment: Now i'm getting the following : `Can not resize 1-th input for a model having 1 inputs.` And this is what i did from the documentation from your link : 
`model=tf.keras.models.load_model('./MyModel.h5')
model.inputs[0].set_shape([None, 1024, 1])

# Convert the model.
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model) `

Comment: And when i remove the resizes, i get the same `Invalid input Tensor index: 1` error msg.